# chroot with sftp on centos 6.5

Tags: linux, centos, sftp, chroot

I'm trying to get sftp working with proper chroot configuration on Centos 6.5 server. As for now I get:

```
sftp user@000.000.000.000
User@000.000.000.000's password: 
Write failed: Broken pipe
Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer
```

In /var/log/messages I get:

```
Connection from 000.000.000.000 port 52365
Accepted password for User from 000.000.000.000 port 52365 ssh2
User child is on pid 0000
fatal: bad ownership or modes for chroot directory component "/"
```

User section in /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
Match User User
        X11Forwarding no
        AllowTcpForwarding no
        ChrootDirectory /sftp/user
```

Both /sftp and /sftp/user are set to root:root and 755. As I understand error message, chroot tries to use "/" as directory, instead of "/sftp/user". Why is it so? What may I do to fix it? Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Can you share an output of `ls -lad /`?

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -lad /
rwxr-xr-x. 30 509 users 4096 Oct 23 13:56 /
```

Showed that root belongs to non existent user and users group.
Simple chown fixed the problem.

```
chown root:root /
```